# Background Tasks in Xamarin

Tags: sockets, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1

In my application I have a Socket Connection to a server, in Android this is running in a Android.App.Service, this works as it should even when the app is 
minimized/suspended. I am no working on the Windows Phone part, I tried to create a new Thread(SendAndRecieveAction) { IsBackground = true }; but when I press the windows button and the application gets minimized all the resources gets cleared (Sockets gets closed even though it has an keep alive packets). How can I implement my Sockets in Windows phone that when the user minimizes the application the Sockets would not end

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone there is no way to run your code permanently in background as a kind of a service. You can use a `PeriodicTask` that opens a socket every time it runs. To learn more about `PeriodicTasks` and background tasks in general you should read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: The problem that I have is that it only runs every 30 minutes from what I read in the link you have given. is there a way to change that ?

Comment: Only for testing purpose as described here (http://windowsphonehacker.com/articles/custom_periodictask_intervals_wpdev-03-10-13). It's not possible to bring an app to the store using this hack. May be you can declare your app as a background audio player that plays a silent audio file infinite times. Here's how to do it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
While it is playing you should be able to keep the socket alive. But this is also a dirty hack. WinPhone doesn't allow apps to run as a background service due to battery life. Deal with it.